# ASP.NET MVC 4 some Routes are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Customer_widget",
    "customer/widget/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Customer_Widget", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

test URL1: (does work)
`customer/widget/contact_list/1-1004-SC-0-0-0-0-0-0-Supplier-Supplier----0-0-0-0-Year-Calendar-0-Home-0`

test URL2: **(does not work)**

```
customer/widget/contact_list/1-1004-SC-0-0-0-0-0-0-Supplier-Supplier--6%2f1%2f2013-7%2f6%2f2013--0-0-0-0-Year-Calendar-0-Home-0  (does not work)
```

I have testes those two URLs above. The first URL goes to the right place. But the second URL just lost its way...
I have no idea what causes this... 
I kind of assume that the daytime part, 6%2f1%2f2013-7%2f6%2f2013, causes some problems but I am not sure what that is.

CustomerController

```
 public ActionResult Index(string id = null)
    {
      string temp = "~/customer/widget/contact_list/" + this.objURL.ToString();
      return Redirect("~/customer/widget/contact_list/" + this.objURL.ToString());
    }
```

Customer_WidgetController

```
  public ActionResult Contact_list(string id = null)
    {
      return PartialView("_contact_list",Customer_Widget.Contact_list.Load(id, ref errors));
    }
```

flow CustomerController ->(by map route) Customer_WidgetController

Answer (score 0):

It's all because of encoded slash '%2f' symbol that corresponds to '/'. Because of this your url

```
customer/widget/contact_list/1-1004-SC-0-0-0-0-0-0-Supplier-Supplier--6%2f1%2f2013-7%2f6%2f2013--0-0-0-0-Year-Calendar-0-Home-0
```

breaking into 8 segments:

1. customer
2. widget
3. contact_list
4. 1-1004-SC-0-0-0-0-0-0-Supplier-Supplier--6
5. 1
6. 2013-7
7. 6
8. 2013--0-0-0-0-Year-Calendar-0-Home-0

but in your route you are expecting 4.

For defining variable count of segments you can use asterisk (*) like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Customer_widget",
    "customer/widget/{action}/{*id}",
    new { controller = "Customer_Widget", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Route system checks routes sequentially. So you need to be careful with this and define route like this as low as possible because it can catch request you don't want to catch with this route. For example if following route will be defined in your system after route above it will never be catched:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Customer_widget",
        "customer/widget/{action}/{lang}/{*id}",
        new { controller = "Customer_Widget", lang = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        new { lang = "en|es|ru"});
```